# Call Module SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas

This code works on PC SAS 9.4 but not on SAS Enterprise Guide. Is there a way to make this work on EG?

```
FILENAME SASCBTBL CATALOG "work.temp.attrfile.source";

DATA _NULL_;
FILE SASCBTBL;
    PUT "ROUTINE WNetGetConnectionA MODULE=MPR MINARG=3 MAXARG=3 STACKPOP=CALLED RETURNS=LONG;";
    PUT "  ARG 1 CHAR INPUT BYADDR FORMAT=$CSTR200.;";
    PUT "  ARG 2 CHAR UPDATE BYADDR FORMAT=$CSTR200.;";
    PUT "  ARG 3 NUM UPDATE BYADDR FORMAT=PIB4.;";
RUN;

%MACRO getUNC;
DATA zz1;
length input_dir $200 output_dir $200;
* The input directory can only be a drive letter + colon ONLY e.g. j: ;
input_dir = 'O:';
output_dir = ' ';
output_len = 200;
call module('*IE',"WNetGetConnectionA", input_dir, output_dir, output_len);
call symputx('dir',input_dir,'l');
call symputx('path',output_dir,'l');
RUN;
%put drive letter is &dir;
%put path is &path;
%MEND getunc;

%getunc;
```

When I try to run it on SAS EG I get the following note:
    ERROR: Module MPR could not be loaded.
    NOTE: Invalid argument to function MODULE('WNetGetConne'[12 of 18 characters shown],'O:          '[12 of 200 characters shown],'
                  '[12 of 200 characters shown],200) at line 54 column 186.
    input_dir=O: output_dir=  output_len=200 *ERROR*=1 *N*=1

Comment: Where is the SAS session that you are using Enterprise Guide to connect to running?  Is it running on the same machine where you got the statement to work?  If not are they at least running the same operating system?

Comment: They are in the same machine.

Comment: Run PROC SETINIT in both environments and compare.the output.  Check the automatic macro variables SYSHOSTINFOLONG and SYSUSERID.

Comment: may `input_dir = O:;` should be write as `input_dir = 'O';`?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. When I edited some macro variables to copy it here I made a typo. Original code has input_dir = 'O';. Even then it is not working.